# Jupyter notebook, ImportError: No module named pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook, conda

I am a ubuntu user, and I have install python 2.7.9 on my computer.
In order to use jupyter notebook, I down load anaconda2.
After my installation, I find after entering the command 'jupyter notebook', my browser will open jupyter notebook, but I can't find new python2, so I went to the https://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html
Use the following commands:

```
conda create -n ipykernel_py2 python=2 ipykernel
source activate ipykernel_py2    
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

Now I do can new python2 on the jupyter notebook, but when I enter the command 'from pylab import *'
it will show the error as ImportError: No module named pylab
but if I open a terminal and enter 'python' and then enter 'from pylab import *', it works all ok.

So, what is the problem? I am new to python and jupyter notebook.
Thank you very much.

Comment: If I run 'import sys' on jupyter, it is also ok. I am totally not familiar with what will happen if I install install python 2.7.9 and anaconda2 on ubuntu. It just work ok when I do it on windows, and I just need to click the jupyter notebook or ipython without set any environment. But on ubuntu, everything seems different and difficult.

Comment: jupyter notebook
[W 13:29:00.091 NotebookApp] Widgets are unavailable. Please install widgetsnbextension or ipywidgets 4.0
[I 13:29:00.106 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/hust/anaconda2/bin
[I 13:29:00.106 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 13:29:00.106 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 13:29:00.106 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
(process:23340): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

Comment: [I 13:29:42.046 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in 
[W 13:29:43.504 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20160426132900 (::1) 11.87ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb?kernel_name=python2
[I 13:29:43.616 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 0b9c634e-686f-43c0-8969-acde3c38888**

Comment: You don't have the relevant modules installed in that environment. With the new environment active, run `conda install matplotlib` (and likewise for any other packages you need).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem.

In terminal:

```
ipython
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.path
Out[2]: 
['',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/bin',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/lib/python27.zip',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/hust/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/hust/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/hust/.ipython']
```

But in jupyter notebook, the sys.path is:

```
 ['',
  '/home/hust/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python27.zip',
  '/home/hust/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7',
  '/home/hust/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
  '/home/hust/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
  '/home/hust/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
  '/home/hust/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
  '/home/hust/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
  '/home/hust/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.7.0-py2.7.egg',
  '/home/hust/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
  '/home/hust/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
  '/home/hust/.ipython']
```

Then I remember I have used the following codes to create a python2 kernel.

```
conda create -n ipykernel_py2 python=2 ipykernel
source activate ipykernel_py2    
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

In the [website](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html)'s description, if you’re running Jupyter on Python 3, you can set up a Python 2 kernel like this. But actually I am running Jupyter on Python 2, the reason why I could not new a python2 script in jupyter notebook should be something else.

Finally, I realize that it is better to master all the pythons' environment via [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/). I should firstly install pyenv and then I only need use these commands, `pyenv install anaconda-2.4.0` , `pyenv global anaconda-2.4.0` and `jupyter notebook`.