# "No Module Named" error in Jupyter

Tags: python

A [very similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854653/jupyter-notebook-importerror-no-module-named-pylab), but different solution.

When I try to do `import speech_recognition as sr` in Jupyter, it returns the `no moduled named...` error.

But doing it in a terminal is fine. So I looked through the sys.paths of both. In Jupyter:

```
//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py3.5.egg',
 '/Users/don',
 '/Users/don/Users/don/Documents/PyModules/skynet',
 '//anaconda/lib/python35.zip',
 '//anaconda/lib/python3.5',
 '//anaconda/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin',
 '//anaconda/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.1-py3.5.egg',
 '//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aeosa',
 '//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/Users/don/.ipython'
```

In terminal:

```
/Users/don/Applications/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages
/datashader-0.4.0-py3.5.egg
/Users/don
/Users/don/Users/don/Documents/PyModules/skynet
/Users/don/Applications/miniconda3/lib/python35.zip
/Users/don/Applications/miniconda3/lib/python3.5
/Users/don/Applications/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin
/Users/don/Applications/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload
/Users/don/Applications/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages
/Users/don/Applications/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg
```

If I run this first in Jupyter, then the module `speech_recognition` imports fine:
`sys.path.append('/Users/don/Applications/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages')`

I'd just like to know what's going on? I've found a solution of sorts, but I'd like a more elegant one, so I don't have to do `sys.path.append` every time. This is particularly endemic to a bunch of modules I've installed lately using `pip install <module>`.

Comment: Are you running jupyter from within an activated conda environment?

Comment: I'm not too sure what that means...could you explain that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fixed it, but I don't know how or why. I just did `$ pip3 install jupyter`, and everything magically imported correctly after that. Nevertheless, if someone could give me a clue about what got fixed (because I don't even know what went wrong), that would be great.